# Good place to generate .json file from SQL in TFS

Tags: tfs, configuration, web-config, release-management

Short story:  I'm trying to identify the most reasonable place in our TFS Build and Release cycle to generate some .json files with snapshot of data from a SQL db.  They need to be generated prior to the final "Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions" task of the release definition, because they will be consumed by that task.

Details:
I have a ASP.NET application that needs to be able to be deployed to multiple environments, and each environment has to have a set of specific settings in its web.config file.

The single source of truth (SST) for what those values should be for each environment is now in a SQL 2016 database.  (Previously there was no SST, which caused >80% of all build and release issues.)

I need to incorporate this SST into the TFS build process and Release Management process to guarantee that the released code for its environment will be guaranteed to have a web.config file with the current values from the SST.

What is a good way to do this?  (Least custom coding while accomplishing the goal.)  Currently, the changes are made using the "Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions" task in the release environment definitions.  However, they currently use their own snapshot of keys/values rather than updated info from the SST. :(

I'm assuming that custom configuration.json files need to be generated from the SQL server as a release step to tokenize the files correctly.  The contents of the json file can be generated with a single SQL statement (Thank you SQL Server 2016 for finally adding .json support)

What [stock tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/index) or community tasks can/should I use to generate the .json file for this?

Comment: So why not to do this (using PowerShell for instance, however personally I would write simple C# app) before the said "Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions" task? I would do this as part of Release (deploys to environments) rather than Build (produces artifacts).

Comment: That's is my last resort plan if there isn't some more standard way to do this with an existing task.  Tiny programs like that often turn into maintenance headaches down the road when versions upgrade, etc.

Comment: @SvdSinner  After go through the tasks in Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Downloads) Seems there is no such one  fully meet your requirement. You may have to the customization by yourself. Either through powershell script or create you own task.